# Why does encoding wav file to base64 with python and online webapp give different results?

Tags: javascript, python, audio, howler.js

I am making a simple web app that needs to play a some audio files, using [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/). howler.js accepts base64 URI as input, so I wanted to try that out. To test it, I took a sample audio file and used an online [audio-to-base64 encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/) to get the base64 URI. I added the data description ("data:audio/wav;base64,") the front of the base64 string and copy and pasted into the following JS function...:

```
function playSound() {
    var data = "";
    var sound = new Howl({
      src: [data],
      loop: false
    });
    sound.play();
}
```

...and it worked perfectly. Since I would be dealing with a fair number of audio files, I figured I'd use a short python script to convert them all to the base64. To test, I converted the same audio to a base64 string with the following python code:

```
import base64
with open("0.wav", "rb") as f1,open("b64.txt", "w") as f2:
    encoded_f1 = base64.b64encode(f1.read())
    f2.write("data:audio/wav;base64,")
    f2.write(str(encoded_f1))
```

I noticed the base64 string was different front the one I got from the website earlier. I pasted this into the JS function shown earlier, but when I attempt to play the sound, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
```

There seems to be some sort of difference in the way python is encoding to base64. What could the cause for this be?

Comment: Where is `atob()` called?

Comment: It's called the howler.js code itself. Check it out here: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/master/dist/howler.core.min.js (the code is in a single line, but a CTRL+F will show you where `atob()` is called).

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co including `data URI` created at `python`?

Comment: Note: [**modified Base64** for URL variants exist, where the '+' and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-' and '_'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

Comment: **Can't reproduce.** Upon closer inspection: both the service you cited and the Python's `base64` encoder use the same (default) alphabet (`+/` for last 2 chars). The only difference is the service wraps its output to 76 characters per line, but that shouldn't matter. There something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Came back to this after a while and the problem became apparent. It was just a problem with the block of code I mentioned in OP (the second block) that I used to write the base64 encoding to a file.

`base64.b64encode(f1.read())` returns a bit string, which in Python, is symbolized with the following notation (i.e. when you print/write it, you'll see it like this): `b'string goes here'`. So the issue was just that the `b' '` was wrapped around my actual base64 string, and I was using that. All I had to do get rid of the `b' '` which I did by converting the bitstring to ASCII like this: `str(encoded_f1,'ascii', 'ignore')`.

Really silly mistake, but hopefully it helps someone out.